# Freenet project search

Tags: search, fetch, freenet

I got Freenet Project's app up and running.
Now I can open "http://localhost:8888/" to display Freenet main menu.
The problem is I want to search through its search function (Browsing -> Search Freenet).
After typing the phrase I want to look for - it loads for a while and displays "Failed to fetch content" so I can't search any content - and that really bothers me.
I can send some log or anything if anyone tells me what to include.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Ondřej Doležal. You have stated some facts, but what's your specific question? You may want to check out [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) in our [help] for some suggestions, and **[edit]** your post to include a specific question that we can provide an answer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freenet's keyword search functionality depends on (anonymous) maintainers of search indexes, running crawlers and indexing the content they encounter. Crawling Freenet is hard work and can be legally challenging. As far as I know, there are no currently maintained search indexes.

By design, Freenet only retains content while it is new, or while it remains popular. The known indexes are outdated, so they are neither new nor popular. This caused them to have disappear from the network almost entirely, which you seem to have experienced first-hand.

Lacking a functional search, there are still other ways to get around Freenet. The default set of bookmarks includes a handful of index sites, such as *Enzo's Index*, that to some end provide an overview of websites available on Freenet. Also note that there's quite an active community on FMS and Sone, which are Freenet's forum and Twitter equivalents, respectively. You can find more about both in the *Freenet Social Networking Guide*, which is also included in the default bookmarks.